# MonoDroid Does Not Support

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin

when I start project it says this error. Every thing is good like(`Xamarin studio, Sdk Manager`) whatever then why it says this?
What i do now?

[image]

Comment: Please post the error log here and also your code!

Answer (score 0):

This error can be generated within Visual Studio when you attempt to Run your app when there are build errors. Visual Studio will attempt to instead run the "previous[ly built] version", which is something that we do not currently support.

Make sure that your project builds without any errors, then attempt to Run your app again.

Source: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/3410/monodroid-does-not-support-running-the-previous-version